Cannot get Nagios to run in browser (401 Unathorized)
For the past 2-3 days at work I've been banging my head over Nagios and trying to make it run with different RHEL based distros (CentOS, AlmaLinux, etc.) However, even after closely following the documentation provided from the official Nagios site and additional links, I simply cannot get it to work. I've tried remaking the .htaccess file, I've tried giving the right permissions and the only way I could get it to "work" is by removing the properties in /etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf.
I do NOT receive an authentication prompt in the browser for username/password but rather:

"Unauthorized This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand
how to supply the credentials required."

! SELinux is disabled !
Nagios 4.4.14 + Apache 2.4.37 (centos)
This is the configuration that should work as intended:
ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">
   Options ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/local/nagios/share"

<Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Nagios Access"
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

Port 80 is open, I've confirmed the apache configuration as well as the virtual hosts:
[root@NagiosSRV nagios]# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex lua-ivm-shm: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/etc/httpd/run/" mechanism=default
Mutex cache-socache: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48

curl works and authenticates properly and the logs confirm it:
[root@NagiosSRV nagios]# curl -u nagiosadmin:nagios -I http://[IP_ADDRESS]/nagios/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2024 12:08:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (centos)
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.24
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


Logs from watch tail /var/log/httpd/access_log:
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2024:12:07:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 199691 "-" "check_http/v2.4.6.git (nagios-plugins 2.4.6)"
4.223.140.114 - nagiosadmin [23/Aug/2024:12:08:11 +0000] "HEAD /nagios/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/7.61.1"
4.223.140.114 - nagiosadmin [23/Aug/2024:12:09:18 +0000] "HEAD /nagios/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "curl/7.61.1"

I've checked for the modules to confirm they're enabled and working:
[root@NagiosSRV nagios]# httpd -M | grep auth
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)

I have no clue what is causing this, I've totally ran out of things to think of. If it's of any help - the ownership of the directories are these:
chown -R apache:apache /usr/local/nagios
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/nagios
chown apache:apache /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users
chmod 640 /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.
